# Почему корову называют Буренкой

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Почему корову называют Буренкой, причем масть животины не имеет значения?

Comment: Конечно же, масть имеет значение.
Буренка, Пеструшка, Белянка, Чалый, Рыжий - все эти клички животных прямо указывают на масть.

Answer (score 8):

БУРЁНКА - Трад.-нар. Ласк. корова (первоначально - распространённая кличка коровы бурой масти). Бурый - это оттенок коричневого цвета - серовато-коричневый, темно-коричневый с красноватым отливом - вероятно, **очень распространенный** в деревнях цвет.

Также «буркой» называют коня бурой масти.

Comment: У нас на юге практически все коровы красно-коричневого цвета (это уже сейчас их черно-белыми разбавили, а раньше были только такие), поэтому такая кличка у меня никогда не вызывала вопросов. )))

Comment: Игра слов бывает непереводимая, а бывает переводимая :) Beurre по-французцки сливочное масло! Теперь сивка-бурка: "Бурак" - легендарное животное, на котором, по преданию, скакал весьма влиятельный исторический персонаж. Да, тот самый на которого не стоит рисовать карикатуры :)

Answer (score 0):

Для меня *"бурёнка" означает: корова бурой масти!*
"Пеструха" — корова пёстрой масти; и т.д.
Коня называют "вороной" — тоже масть!
Вспомните песню, которую исполнял Л. О. Утёсов: "Ты не только съела цветы..."
Там корова — Пеструха!